# add authorization header in simple get request

Tags: axios, get, request-headers, preflight

I need to add authorization header in simple get request but i cant do that because simple request doesnt allow custom header, i tried to add it in link as parameter query but it doesnt work.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    axios
      .get("demo/api", {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "text/plain"
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  },[])
```

I tried add custom headers but not work.